# WCF object within DataContract

Tags: c#, wcf, object, datacontract, datamember

[Edit]: I added the TokenType enum, what caused the whole issue...

I have an issue using WCF and unfortunately I didn't find any useful help.
I am creating a WCF based application. When the server responds to the client's request, I want the send back the following class:

```
[DataContract]
public enum TokenType
{
    User,
    Device
}

[DataContract]
public class AuthenticationResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public LogonStatus Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public AccessToken Token { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public struct AccessToken
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TokenID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public TokenType Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Uid
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime ExpirationTime
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime GenerationTime
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsExpired
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now > this.ExpirationTime;
        }
    }
}
```

When I send the AuthenticationResponse back to the client, it always fails.
My qusetion: Is there any chance to use class/struct objects within DataContract object or do I have to replace the AccessToken object with basic types (e.g. string) in the AuthenticationResponse object?

Thanks all your helps!
Best regards

Gabor

Comment: What kind of "fails"?

Comment: The data sending from server to client fails until 

[DataMember]
    public AccessToken Token { get; set; }

is not null in AuthenticationResponse class. If it is null or changed with string type properties, everything works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh...
Sorry for that. I was really stupid... I forgot to paste the TokenType enum in my original question what is part of AuthenticationResponse class, and this was the problem... I forget the set the [EnumMember] attributes...

After I added, everything worked well.

Sorry for this stupid and really beginner problem...

Thanks all your helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `public bool IsExpired` has no setter and thus cause problems while serializing the object.

A workaround is to set a protected/private setter to your property with an empty body (or replace it by a method)

```
[DataMember]
public bool IsExpired
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.Now > this.ExpirationTime;
    }
    set
    {
        /* Dummy setter for serialization fix */
    }
}
```

You can find more information about Serialization here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx

More specifically :

> Items That Can Be Serialized
>
> The following items can be serialized using the XmLSerializer class:
>
> ```
> Public read/write properties and fields of public classes
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the one issue with my object. :-)

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as the answer to close your question.